# Journey Goals based on email metrics

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, data-views, goals

Is it possible to establish a Goal in a Journey based on the % of Open / Clicks / etc of an email within the journey?

I see a Goal can be only set based on Contact Data, so I was thinking in create a Data Extension with the information of the Data Views to store that information in a field (e.g. boolean) updated periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the solution described in your question (having a helper data extension that contains the goal attainment data written by an automation) should work, if you consider the following:

- Make sure your helper data extension has a 1:1 relationship to the subscriber and is connected to the data model in Contact Builder / Data Designer
- If your entry mode allows for multiple entries, journey builder won't distinguish between the individual journey entries of one unique subscriber
- Run the automation setting your helper data extension regularly so you have accurate data every time a contact approaches an activity where your goal attainment is of importance

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick response. The second point is not really clear to me. Does it mean that this approach doesn't work for a journey in re-entry mode?

Comment: At least you wouldn't be able to have different goal results for multiple entries (if they are present at the same time). If the re-entry is set to "only after exiting" and you make sure the helper DE only contains the most recent data, this will work fine.